# Do we have any API to fetch configurations based on location in softlayer?

Tags: java, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Currently we are using below API to fetch configurations from softlayer.

https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getCreateObjectOptions

Answer (score 0):

the https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getCreateObjectOptions return the valid configurations that you can do, and it should be available in the all the data centers, In case the configuration is not available in a datacenter you will get an error message